# Logstash sending logs from files that was processed

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash, elk

Logstash sending logs from files that was processed and saved to sincedb file but only from files that are marked as type_2. There is a config file.

```
input {
  file {
    add_field => { "[@metadata][type]" => "type_1" }
    path => "/opt/ftp/folder*/*.log"
    exclude => "/opt/ftp/folder*/*.log.gz"
    mode => "read"
    file_completed_action => "log"
    file_completed_log_path => "/opt/ftp/type_1_completed.log"
    sincedb_path => "/opt/ftp/type_1_sincedb.log"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^%{DATE} %{TIME}"
      negate => true
      what => "previous"
      max_lines => 3000
      multiline_tag => ""
    }
  }
  file {
    add_field => { "[@metadata][type]" => "type_2" }
    path => "/opt/ftp/folder*/*.log.gz"
    mode => "read"
    file_completed_action => "log"
    file_completed_log_path => "/opt/ftp/type_2_completed.log"
    sincedb_path => "/opt/ftp/type_2_sincedb.log"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^%{DATE} %{TIME}"
      negate => true
      what => "previous"
      max_lines => 3000
      multiline_tag => ""
    }
  }
}

filter
{#whatever}

output
{
  if [@metadata][type] == "type_1" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => #hosts
      user => #user
      password => #password
      index => "type_1"
    }
  }
  if [@metadata][type] == "type_2" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => #hosts
      user => #user
      password => #password
      index => "type_2"
    }
  }
}
```

As an interesting observation - got my view on _sincedb.log files. type_1 looks normal to me

```
[user@ftp_server ~]$ cat /opt/ftp/type_1_sincedb.log
123 0 64771 56 88.92 /opt/ftp/folder1/type_1_1.log
124 0 64771 56 78.91 /opt/ftp/folder1/type_1_2.log
125 0 64771 56 79.90 /opt/ftp/folder1/type_1_3.log
...
```

But type_2 got something weird (maybe it will help to understand something to someone)

```
[user@ftp_server ~]$ cat /opt/ftp/type_2_sincedb.log
123 0 64771 56 88.92
124 0 64771 56 78.91
125 0 64771 56 79.90 /opt/ftp/folder1/type_2_6.log.gz
...
```

Somehow only last line has its filename and after logstash process this file completely - it will remove filename at the end.

```
[user@ftp_server ~]$ cat /opt/ftp/type_2_sincedb.log
123 0 64771 56 88.92
124 0 64771 56 78.91
125 0 64771 56 79.90
126 0 64771 56 85.99 /opt/ftp/folder1/type_2_7.log.gz
...
```

```
[user@ftp_server ~]$ logstash --version
Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
logstash 8.7.1
```

UPD: logstash seems to overwrite `/opt/ftp/type_2_sincedb.log` for some reason because after restart and waiting until the middle of the logs processing - found out that `type_2_sincedb.log` got less information that it was before restart.

UPD2: tried to make one sincedb_path for both type of files. Made it by `mv` command to `type_1_sincedb.log` and `type_1_completed.log` files to `sincedb.log` and `completed.log`. `completed.log` got information about new files but `sincedb.log` stays unchanged. Both file set to `644` mod.

UPD3: found out [those](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file/issues/286) [two](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file/issues/311) links. My type_2 files are indeed .gz and they're not saving properly in sincedb file. Maybe some workaround?